# Как задать KeyValue для timeline'а для анимации движения?

Tags: javafx, анимация

пытаюсь сделать простую анимацию движения круга. Создавая timeline создаю новый KeyFrame, для него же создаю KeyValue(cira.centerXProperty(),100), где cira - упомянутый круг. Выдает ошибку:'KeyValue' is abstract; cannot be instantiate. Как решить?

```
@FXML
Circle cira = new Circle();
KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(cira.centerXProperty(),100);
```

Comment: Найти классы наследники `KeyValue` и использовать их.

Comment: У вас Circle имеет аннотацию @FXML, объект будет создан fxmlLoader'om, создавать его самостоятельно ненужно.

Comment: Решено, проблема крылась в криво подключенной библиотеке. Спасибо за ваши ответы!

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/animations/basics.htm#CJAFADFJ

Example 1-5 Timeline Animation

```
final Rectangle rectBasicTimeline = new Rectangle(100, 50, 100, 50);
rectBasicTimeline.setFill(Color.RED);
...
final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
timeline.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
final KeyValue kv = new KeyValue(rectBasicTimeline.xProperty(), 300);
final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500), kv);
timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);
timeline.play();
```